# Undefined method in eval()

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Eval() is used to eval a `workflow` block in Rails 4.2 model `payment_request`. Here is the `workflow` block before using `eval`:

```
  class PaymentRequest < ActiveRecord::Base
    include Workflow
    def self.load_wf
      workflow do
        state :initial_state do
          event :submit, :transitions_to => :ceo_reviewing
        end
        state :ceo_reviewing do
          event :reject, :transitions_to => :rejected
          event :approve, :transitions_to => :approved
        end
        state :rejected
        state :approved
      end
    end
    ..........
  end
```

String variable `spec` is defined as:

```
spec = "state :initial_state do
    event :submit, :transitions_to => :ceo_reviewing
  end
  state :ceo_reviewing do
    event :reject, :transitions_to => :rejected
    event :approve, :transitions_to => :approved
  end
  state :rejected
  state :approved"
```

And rewrite:

```
  class PaymentRequest < ActiveRecord::Base
    include Workflow
    def self.load_wf(spec)
      eval("Workflow::ClassMethods.workflow {#{spec}}")    
    end
     ...............
  end
```

The `eval` generates error:

`undefined method 'workflow' for Workflow::ClassMethods:Module.`

`workflow` is a method in a gem:

```
module Workflow
  module ClassMethods
    attr_reader :workflow_spec
    .....
    def workflow(&specification)
      assign_workflow Specification.new(Hash.new, &specification)
    end
    ......
  end
end
```

Tried to add binding in eval and it did not work (not sure if the binding is used correctly). How to make `eval` find method `workflow` & execute it in the model `payment_request`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem here is you're trying to call a method before it's been properly mixed in. The way the module's intended to be used is [documented on the home page](https://github.com/geekq/workflow). Since you're doing this dynamically you need to try and match it as closely as possible.

That is, do something like this:

```
class PaymentRequest < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Workflow

  def self.load_wf(spec)
    instance_eval("workflow {#{spec}}")    
  end
end
```

The `workflow` method should be defined in the context you're executing in here, that being the `PaymentRequest` class, and using `instance_eval` might set it up with the correct bindings. `eval` might work, so try that too.

Comment: The step I am approaching this problem is step1#run `load_wf` with plain code and without any `eval`. After step1 works, then step2# replace the code with `eval`. The problem happens at step2 after introducing `eval`.. In step1, `workflow` is called successfully and I did not see mixin issue. I feel it is more likely a scope (binding) with `eval` as you indicated in another post. But there are not much online about `binding` except some definition.

Comment: Before posting, I tried `instance_eval`, `class_eval` and they returns the same error.

Comment: You could do some testing, like `instance_eval("raise self.methods.inspect")` to see if it's even there. It should be!

Comment: A simplest form works: eval("workflow {#{spec}}") where spec="state :rejected". I may be over complicated by adding `Workflow::ClassMethods`.

Comment: Now the matter becomes how to compose the spec definition into a readable string fed to `workflow`

Comment: You shouldn't ever refer to `ClassMethods` directly. They won't work on their own. That's the internals of the module.